# In Blazor, how do I make changes to an injected object be reflected in all components? (AKA reactivity)

Tags: blazor

In a Blazor WebAssembly site, suppose I have a class

```
    public class State : IState
    {
        public bool ShowEasterEggs { get; set; } = false;
    }
```

And I properly register it in my client's Program.cs: `builder.Services.AddSingleton<IState, State>();`

And I properly inject this into a component:

```
@inject IState State
@if (State.ShowEasterEggs)
{
  <span>EASTER EGGS SHOWN</span>
}
```

And in some other component, I enable a change to it:

```
@inject IState State
<input type="checkbox" @bind="State.ShowEasterEggs"/>Show Easter Eggs
```

I expect that a change to State.ShowEasterEggs from the second component would be detected and any instance of the first component would update automatically.  But I find that I need to do some other interaction--changing other values
in the first component's parent, to see the change in the first component's instance.

So how does this work, how should it work, and how can I get changes to injected objects to cause an update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [Cascading values and parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components?view=aspnetcore-3.1#cascading-values-and-parameters)

You would need to have a `CascadingValue` component that is parent of any component that will react to the changes.

`CascadingValue` will receive a property called `Value` that will hold the value you want to the children to see (`State`).

And you will get that property in your child components and pass an attribute `CascadingParameter` to a property with the same name you passed in `CascadingValue`'s `Value` attribute.

e.g. from the docs

The parent

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase
@using BlazorSample.UIThemeClasses

@inject IState State @* Injecting the State *@

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <NavMenu />
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <CascadingValue Value="State"> @* Passing State as a Cascading Value*@
                <div class="content px-4">
                    @Body
                </div>
            </CascadingValue>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any child component

```
<input type="checkbox" @bind="State.ShowEasterEggs"/>Show Easter Eggs

@code {

    // Getting the Cascading Value as a parameter
    [CascadingParameter]
    protected State State { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it.  Is there any way to have global or pseudo-global values except through CascadingValue?

Comment: @PatrickSzalapski not sure, but if you want to react to changes, I think `CascadingValue` is the only way

Comment: In this example, only changes to State that happen from the parent will cascade down, right?  In other words, a change in a child component will not affect other child components?

Comment: @PatrickSzalapski `only changes to State that happen from the parent will cascade down` yes, that is true.

Comment: @PatrickSzalapski `a change in a child component will not affect other child components` this depends on what you mean by `a change in a child component`. If you change the property that have the attribute `CascadingParameter`, then the parent will rerender all change all childs, if you change other property that isn't `CascadingParameter`, than only that child will rerender.

Comment: @PatrickSzalapski Here is a [explanation](https://chrissainty.com/understanding-cascading-values-and-cascading-parameters/)  of how cascading values work. Please take a look at `Updating Cascading Values` section  if you still have questions on how it works.

Answer (score 4):

There are various ways to do it. The following one is sort of a service that implements the State pattern and the Notifier pattern:

### State.cs

```
 public interface IState
{
    event Action Notify;
    bool ShowEasterEggs { get; set; }
}
public class State : IState
{
    public event Action Notify;

    bool showEggs = false;
    public bool ShowEasterEggs
    {
        get => showEggs;
        set
        {
            if (showEggs != value)
            {
                showEggs = value;

                if (Notify != null)
                {
                    Notify?.Invoke();
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

### Child1.razor

```
 @inject IState State

 <input type="checkbox" @bind="State.ShowEasterEggs" />Show Easter Eggs
 <hr />


 @code {

 }
```

### Child2.razor

```
 @inject IState State
 @implements IDisposable

@if (State.ShowEasterEggs)
{
    <span>EASTER EGGS SHOWN</span>
}

<hr />


@code {
   protected override void OnInitialized()
  {
       State.Notify += OnNotify;
  }

 public void OnNotify()
 {
    InvokeAsync(() =>
    {
        StateHasChanged();
    });
}

public void Dispose()
{
    State.Notify -= OnNotify;
}
}
```

### Index.razor

```
 @page "/"

 <Child1></Child1>
 <Child2></Child2>



 @code { }
```

### Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IState, State>();
```

AS you've probably noticed, the State service store the state of the check box, and notify subscribers of changes to this state.

Hope this helps...

Comment: I think this one should be marked as correct answer. This is the better way to implement reactivity in blazor.